# Как сделать эффект рисования прямоугольника?

Tags: python, pyqt5, tkinter, kivy

Есть задача сделать функцию, в которой на изображении надо нарисовать прямоугольник.

Нужно, чтобы нажатие мыши задавало верхнюю левую точку прямоугольника, а отпускание-конечную. Причем во время этого процесса дорисовывался пунктиром сам прямоугольник.

Подскажите пожалуйста, с помощью какой библиотеки такое можно реализовать (в предпочтениях kivy, но готов написать функционал и на tkinter, и на pyqt5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На **PyQt5** это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets  


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap('im.png').scaled(QtCore.QSize(660, 620))
 
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self) 
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.pix)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 3, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        br = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("transparent"))
        qp.setBrush(br)
        if self.begin and self.end:
            rect = QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end)
            qp.drawRect(rect)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.begin = event.pos()
            self.end = self.begin
            self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.end = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.pix)
            rect = QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 3, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawRect(rect)
            self.begin = self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.resize(660, 620)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, сделал реализацию на kivy, правда костыльно, с добавлением и удалением координат линий, но все же

Comment: Спасибо, сделал реализацию на kivy, правда костыльно, с добавлением и удалением координат линий, но все же

Comment: Спасибо, сделал реализацию на kivy, правда костыльно, с добавлением и удалением координат линий, но все же